# How to setup jquery ui dialog display

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, alert, jquery-ui-dialog

i have code in form

- no submit any thing: `<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>`
- submit : `<div class="screen-reader-response" role="alert">My Content alert<div>`

i'm user code :

```
$( ".screen-reader-response" ).dialog();
```

problems : when i'm don't submit any thing is: echo dialog with no content

how to setup:

if: no submit any thing: `<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>` no echo alert
if: have submit: `<div class="screen-reader-response" role="alert">My Content alert<div>` echo alert `My Content alert`

give me any idea?

visit my site: http://www.graylinecruisehalong.net/ always dialog content when don't submit?

Comment: Clarify your question and put a JSFiddle example

Comment: how to run jquery ui in JSFiddle? 

no submit any thing: http://jsfiddle.net/sfmoetrs/
submit: http://jsfiddle.net/sfmoetrs/1/

Answer (score 1):

**When no submit:**

```
$(".screen-reader-response").html("").dialog('open');
```

**When submit:**

```
$(".screen-reader-response").html("My Content alert").dialog('open');
```

To initialize dialog with more options then please check the documentation of jquery dialog at: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: i'm use `$( ".screen-reader-response" ).dialog();` is run, but don't want run if no content in #myDialog

Comment: Yes, i have update the code. Please check it. I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: i'm add code : when no submit => no echo dialog (true) - but when i'm sumit => no echo dialog (false) ???

Comment: `$(".screen-reader-response").html("My Content alert").dialog('open');     ` if `html("My Content alert")` have not one value ?? how to open ?

Comment: For that I have mentioned in the answer right as when no submit.

Comment: Drop your contact no. 'll call you and help you...!!